# Use external file with Newspaper3k

Tags: python, summarize, python-newspaper

I'm performing a number of scraping and summary tasks and have found that newspaper works perfectly for my (most of) my needs. I have a series of pdf files I also need to look at and perform similar tasks with. I can find other apps to open and extract the stories from, hoping to just feed newspaper the text directly and get it to do its thing.... however, so far I have been unable to figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: The simplest way is to run [`htmltotext`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/poppler-utils) in a subprocess to extract the text. You could also check out [pdfminer](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six)

Comment: I've got that part of it... it's the 'how to feed the resulting text to Newspaper that is the issue.

Comment: I don't think newspaper is the right tool for the job. It's meant for html and web pages. Pdf files are a completely different beast, and typically meant to be consumed by printers or rendered to screen. A pdf file might contain usable metadata or it might not. Trying to reverse engineer the content of a pdf will typically involve a lot of guessing. Mining/scraping pdfs should usually be a last resort, only used if there's no other way to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great package that can deal with your predicament: pymupdf, see

https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Then run:

```
import fitz
```

and follow the docs.